# Можно ли и как написать 2D игру на стандартных библиотеках Java?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, 2d

Хочу написать простенькую 2D-игру типа Mario или Worms на Java без сторонних библиотек, подскажите какие стандартные библиотеки использовать?

Comment: `без сторонних библиотек, подскажите какие библиотеки использовать`

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду из стандартных библиотек???

Comment: @Drakonoved asm - слабость, даешь в машинных кодах

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы у меня все было и мне за это ничего не было

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, извините за тафтологию

Comment: @MZaytsev, да, используя только стандартные

Comment: @ivankarman libgdx https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com

Comment: пример написания игры на чистой Java без сторонних библиотек https://github.com/raydac/battleships-resurrection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно обойтись стандартными AWT или Swing входящими в состав JavaSE, используя для вывода графики Canvas и кодировать все на примитивных средствах. Но вот нужно ли это делать? Эти средства не заточены для игр и имеют определенные проблемы с гладкостью анимаций и скоростью работы с ними.

Если уж создавать игры, то использовать нормальные библиотеки вроде [SFML (прекращена разработка в 2016)](https://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php), [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/) или [LITEngine для 2D](https://litiengine.com/).